# Make a box's width adjust depending on text

Tags: html, css

I'm making a server status-site for my gaming community. I stumbled upon an issue with a box not changing height with the text.

[This is the site](http://trinityplay.net/status/issues/server-maintenance-16-06.php)

And this is my CSS at the moment:

```
.explain_container {
    border: 1px solid #BFC4C7;
    background: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5A5A5A;
}
.explain_text {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="explain_container">
    <div class="explain_text">
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
    </div>
</div>
```

There's supposed to be about 50px margin on all 4 sides.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not a scrollable one? Scrollable one seems more reasonable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it fairly easy by just using .explain_container and using padding on all sides! Without defining the height at all!

Comment: Yes, this does indeed make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.explain_container {
border: 1px solid #BFC4C7;
background: white;
width: 1000px;
position: relative;
font-size: 14px;
color: #5A5A5A;
}
.explain_text {
width: 900px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="explain_container">
        <div class="explain_text">
            Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Remove height for Divs and also remove top position

Answer (score 0):

By adding the top offset to the inner container you move it relative to the outer one. You were going to add `top:50px` to the outer container.

Demo:

```css
.explain_container {
border: 1px solid #BFC4C7;
background: white;
width: 1000px;
height: 120px;
position: relative;
font-size: 14px;
color: #5A5A5A;
top: 50px;
}
.explain_text {
width: 900px;
height: 50px;
position: relative;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="explain_container">
    <div class="explain_text">
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple issues. The first, as @nicael mentioned, is that the top property was added. But also, you need to remove the explicit height properties on each of the containers. If you want to add space between the text and the container, use padding. Replace the current height with `height: auto`, like so:

```css
.explain_container {
  border: 1px solid #BFC4C7;
  background: white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5A5A5A;
}
.explain_text {
  width: 900px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="explain_container">
    <div class="explain_text">
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
        Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you should remove the `height` of `explain_container`, and instead set it as auto.
Then instead of `margin` use `padding`.

[This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5v7jL9jm/) can be a possible solution.

```css
.explain_container {
  border: 1px solid #BFC4C7;
  background: white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5A5A5A;
}

.explain_text {
  width: 900px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="explain_container">
  <div class="explain_text">
    Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend
    the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
    Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should
    extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the
    box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box. Text that's longer should extend the height of the box.
  </div>
</div>
```